# Linear gradient color for button background color with CurvedNavigationBar in flutter app

Tags: flutter, linear-gradients

Used curved_navigation_bar package for curved navigation bar. And then want to use the navigation bar button background color to linear gradient color. How to set linear gradient color for each button.

```
bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
            index: currentIndex,
            animationCurve: Curves.elasticOut,
            height: 50.0,
            color: headerColor,
            backgroundColor: secondColor,
            buttonBackgroundColor: ...   // In here I want to use linear gradient color.
            items: <Widget>[
              productIcon,
              agentIcon,
              homeIcon,
              postIcon,
              profileIcon,
            ],
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                currentIndex = index;
              });
            },
          ),
```

[image]

I want to change button background like in image. Please advice me.

Comment: You can wrap the button with Container and use BoxDecoration to get gradient

Comment: I know that, I want to only gradient when onTap this button. If I warp each icons with container and set gradient, they are always gradient whenever tap or not.